# How to copy a host's entire disk to another, with checksum?

Tags: linux, rsync, file-transfer

Both servers are running Linux. Is rsync a suitable choice? I know it's suitable for large file transfer, file synchronization etc. But not sure about a) entire disks b) checksums. Thanks in advance.

PS: Already read [How to copy a huge file to a remote shared folder?](https://serverfault.com/questions/564706/how-to-copy-a-huge-file-to-a-remote-shared-folder). Did not answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you'll be able to checksum an entire drive is to un-mount the desired filesystem and then checksum it:

(assuming that `/dev/sdb` is mounted to `/mnt/foo`)

```
$ umount /mnt/foo
$ md5sum /dev/sdb
...
```

Once you have the checksum, you can use `dd` piped through ssh to transfer the entire block device to another system:

```
$ dd if=/dev/sdb | ssh user@host "dd of=/path/to/destination/device"
```

If you're amenable to using ZFS, though, this all gets *much* easier, as you can snapshot an entire filesystem and then send that snapshot in a very efficient manner to a remote server. With ZFS, nearly *everything* is checksummed, and you can be assured that the remote copy will match the local copy bit-for-bit.

Comment: I read that `rsync` is preferred to `dd` becuase it lets you resume the transfer if it is interrupted. Is that so?